# How can I get the screen position of an object (e.g. the eyes)

Tags: spark-ar-studio

Is there a way to get the pixel positions of objects in the scene? SparkAR internally obviously knows where to draw an object, so do they offer an interface to use this information?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `this.sceneObject.worldTransform` for this.

Comment: are you sure? I did not find anything about pixelcoordinates in the docu (https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/scenemodule.worldtransform/)